# Is dhruvaloka temporary region?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, krishna, rama, vishnu-purana

I am wondering , whether the dhruvaloka which was bestowed to Prince Dhruva by Vishnu is eternal or it will be there only for a kalpa.

Here are the [quotes](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc115948.html#note-e-58693) from Vishnu purana

> A station shall be assigned to thee, Dhruva, above the three
>   worlds[8]; one in which thou shalt sustain the stars and the planets;
>   a station above those of the sun, the moon, Mars, the son of Soma
>   (Mercury), Venus, the son of Sūrya (Saturn), and all the other
>   constellations; above the regions of the seven Ṛṣis, and the
>   divinities who traverse the atmosphere[9]. Some celestial beings
>   endure for four ages; some for the reign of a Manu: to thee shall be
>   granted the duration of a Kalpa. Thy mother Sunīti, in the orb of a
>   bright star, shall abide near thee for a similar term;

Comment: No Answers from anyone? . Looks like this question is ignored

Comment: As per your description the station is already there for durva to occupy kalpa pralaya even earth will be submerged so do durga lokha

Comment: @tekkk It was created for dhruva, so it will probably get destroyed once dhruva's life is over, since the purpose of its creation was accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

Dhruvaloka which is a manifestation of Vaikunthaloka within the universe is eternal. It is extolled with the same attributes and appellations(like paramampadam) as the Mahā-Vaikuntha situated beyond Prakriti in the Srimad Bhagavatam. The following quotes from Srimad Bhagavatam about the Dhruvaloka prove this point:

> ŚB 4.9.28:
> विदुर उवाच सुदुर्लभं यत्परमं पदं हरे- र्मायाविनस्तच्चरणार्चनार्जितम् । लब्ध्वाप्यसिद्धार्थमिवैकजन्मना कथं स्वमात्मानममन्यतार्थवित् ॥
>
> ŚB 4.12.26:
> अनास्थितं ते पितृभिरन्यैरप्यङ्ग कर्हिचित् । आतिष्ठ जगतां वन्द्यं तद्विष्णो: परमं पदम् ॥
>
> ŚB 5.22.17:
> तत उत्तरस्माद‍ृषय एकादशलक्षयोजनान्तर उपलभ्यन्ते य एव लोकानां शमनुभावयन्तो भगवतो विष्णोर्यत्परमं पदं प्रदक्षिणं प्रक्रमन्ति ॥
>
> ŚB 5.23.1:
> श्रीशुक उवाच अथ तस्मात्परतस्त्रयोदशलक्षयोजनान्तरतो यत्तद्विष्णो: परमं पदमभिवदन्ति यत्र ह महाभागवतो ध्रुव औत्तानपादिरग्निनेन्द्रेण प्रजापतिना कश्यपेन धर्मेण च समकालयुग्भि: सबहुमानं दक्षिणत: क्रियमाण इदानीमपि कल्पजीविनामाजीव्य उपास्ते तस्येहानुभाव उपवर्णित: ॥

Vishnu purāņa(2.8.98-103) also describes Dhruvaloka similarly as paramampadam(the supreme abode).

An interesting fact is that Hiranyakshipu considers Vishnuloka to be destructible during pralaya as per ŚB 7.3.11. This is appropriate since asuras and specifically abhaktas are deluded by Bhagavan's māyā and think that his body, abode and associates can be destroyed. All abodes of the Lord within the universe are identical and of the same nature as the Mahāvaikuntha beyond prakRti.

(This view is as per Sri Jiva Goswami of the Gaudiya Vaishnava sampradaya and has been inspired from his Bhagavat-sandarbha(Anuccheda 72))

Comment: Welcome to HSE! You can join the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) for general discussion on dharma with Naruto and getting your bearings about the site.